# Email message ID clarification

Tags: java, php, email

I have a small query regarding Email message ID formats which transport over meta data. As far as I know, all the required email ID have the below format.

> <623219229.74.1497295873179@qtbx12.prod.google.com>

But I have found some message ID which has following format.

> <623219229.74.1497295873179>

What I want to know is some sample domains who sends message ID as above.

Sample Meta Data

```
Message ID  <623219229.74.1497295873179@qtbx12.prod.google.com>
Created at: Tue, Jun 13, 2017 at 1:01 AM (Delivered after 0 seconds)
From:   Inbox by Gmail <inbox+noreply@google.com>
To: dasith@gmail.com
Subject:    Welcome to Inbox by Gmail
SPF:    PASS with IP 2607:f8b0:4002:c05:0:0:0:230 Learn more
DKIM:   PASS with domain google.com Learn more
DMARC:  PASS Learn more
```

Comment: Generating the message id is up to the client that sends the email, or if that one fails to do so, the first mail server in the chain will generate it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID

Comment: Thank @CBroe for the information. Can I know whether it has a standard format ?

Comment: Check the Wikipedia article, it references the relevant RFC.